# Visual Basic C# windows form background worker object movement loop not functioning as intended

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, backgroundworker

I'm currently attempting to write a classic snake sort of game, where the user directs the snake around the screen using the keyboard's arrow keys. So far, i've managed to sort out the code that dictates the movement and the keyboard controls successfully, but have come across problems upon trying to merge these pieces of code.

To move the snake, i'm using individual background worker loops for each arrow key as such:

```
    public void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                if (abortloop == true)
                {
                    worker2 = null;
                    worker3 = null;
                    worker4 = null;
                    break;
                }
                while (Snake1.Top - 5 >= 8)
                {
                    {
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            Snake1.Top = Snake1.Top - 5;
                                 Refresh(); 
                        });
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);



                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

where the background worker is called from the keyboard input:

```
 else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            abortloop2 = true;
            abortloop3 = true;
            abortloop4 = true;
            if (worker == null && abortloop == true)
            {
                abortloop = false;
                worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

All this code produces no fatal errors to the program so to speak, however, upon commanding the snake to move in another direction (in this case, let's say it's currently moving downwards and i press the right arrow key), the snake will begin to move in the appropriate direction but also carry moving in the same direction as before (upon pressing the right arrow key, the snake then starts moving diagonally, rather than just to the right as i would want it to). This problem simply isn't down to there being 4 separate background workers, as the same problem occurs if i just use 1 background worker for all of the key inputs.

If anybody here could help out, that'd be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are *many* problems with your code.  Sharing a variable like *abortloop* requires synchronization when it can be read and written by more than one thread.  You can't synchronize a thread that's sleeping.  Get ahead by dropping threads and implement a game loop instead.  You'll get decent google hits from "winforms game loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the while with an if...

```
if (Snake1.Top - 5 >= 8)
```

The looping should be left to the outside for, and you merely want to CHECK for space, and not keep decreasing Top in the inner loop. ;-)

Comment: Wow, i spent so much time trying to solve it and all i had to do was that.. haha. Cheers for the spot on advice though C.B.! :)